# Setting an ID on a new model

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Is it possible to create a new instance of a model and setting it's ID? Whenever I try to do that, the model gets persisted, but the ID is set to the next available number in the MySQL auto-increment list.

For example I want to create a new Sensor like this:

```
s = new Sensor()
s.id = 14
s.name = 'my sensor'
db.session.add(s)
db.session.commit()

saved_instance = Sensor.query.get(14)
assert saved_instance is not None
```

The assert fails.

Comment: Can you check just after the commit what the s.id is?  Could it be that your table has a trigger which sets an id and does not check if it is already set?

Comment: What backend are you using? What the echoed SQL look like?

Comment: Please update your post with the declaration of the `Sensor` class.  Can you confirm this behave occurs when you use `sqlite` as the backend?  easy to test --> `engine = create_engine('sqlite://')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go on a limb (since you haven't provided the information that will let me know for sure) but I believe your sensor declaration uses an auto-increment. If that's the case then setting it before hand will be completely ignored.

```
sensor = Table('sensor', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key = True),
```

In `MySQL` primary keys come pre-packaged with an auto-increment.

For most databases (including `MySQL`), if ID 14 has ever existed in your database then the auto-increment will not allow that number to be used again during the creation phase. Even if you've deleted the row that held ID 14.

You can go back after the fact and update the row to have a different ID provided that ID doesn't already exist in the system.

```
s = new Sensor()
s.id = 14
s.name = 'my sensor'
db.session.add(s)
db.session.commit()

saved_instance = Sensor.query.get(14)
print(saved_instance is not None) # Should fail.

print(s.id) # will return the ID that was actually inserted.
s.update().\
    where(users.c.id==s.id).\
    values(id=14)
```

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, but my ID field does indeed use an auto increment. What you do here programatically is basically what I do by hand currently. I was afraid this was the only way to do this, it seems very hackish, but if it's the only way, that's what it has to be. Thanks for the help!

Comment: In most databases there's a set of assumptions built into `auto increment` and one of those is that your value is monotonically increasing. There's a bunch of database features that become very dangerous if that assumption is broken, which is why the `MySQL` doesn't create ID's again after the first use.